# Регулярное выражение на JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть скрипт, который должен выдирать из ответа сервера часть текста. Но не могу разобраться с регуляркой, она только первое слово обрабатывает, а дальше нет.

Код:

```
+xhr.responseText.match(/_COOKIE.*?(.*?)<\/td><\/tr>/m)[1]
```

Или подскажите регулярку, чтобы ВЕСЬ ответ сервера выдергивала.

Должно куки проверить, строка в ответе сервера, ее и нужно получить. Выглядит так:

> HTTP_COOKIE =>
>   __cfduid=d7a5bc6e25f6043evev21781dbb1d591bd8b1460834789; cf_clearance=b743425f1830b8averea106810887d155501c350d-1460834814-604800;
>   login=yXRWPuMMQ2sd dfSgc%252F0KM985nSZ6cDNwuaFfA%253D%253D;
>   password=31567518v43v43b3975711da84e068fa78;
>   chat_token=P38SgjlpTok4KfdfvbedfvnRKIxWuAxK4OHBkWBLnlrDe%2BxMNQ%3D;
>   user_id=78001175; real_user_id=78001175; social_id=296400;
>   __auc=333d543ga154208ab39c1e7529ec; OAGEO=NL%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C;
>   OAID=d4f0c5982d3sdfva46de6bf377999630; _ym_uid=1460834849654078056;
>   __utma=4986037.946172708.1460834854.1460841308.1460868718.3; __utmc=4986037; __utmz=4986037.1460834854.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _ym_isad=2; __unam=7639673-154208d00a

Comment: Вам что конкретно нужно?  Ответ с сервера получить? Куки с сервера?

Comment: я эту книжку наверно всем уже предлагал здесь - могу бесплатно тебе скинуть книгу по регуляркам 2015 года - на ozon стоит 2000R - если надо пиши - я скину

Comment: добавьте начальный текст и ожидаемый результат

Comment: Это примерно 10 строка в ответе , нужно ее выдрать из ответа. Но если есь регулярка что бы весь ответ выдрать, то тоже подойдет . В таком виде +xhr.responseText не срабатывает. А вот с регуляркой срабатывает, но не полностью.

Comment: Вы тут это. Не выражайтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Если я верно понял задание, то вот мой вариант решения, можно было конечно без JQuery, но суть то не в этом

```js
var someString = "HTTP_COOKIE => __cfduid=d7a5bc6e25f6043evev21781dbb1d591bd8b1460834789; cf_clearance=b743425f1830b8averea106810887d155501c350d-1460834814-604800; login=yXRWPuMMQ2sd dfSgc%252F0KM985nSZ6cDNwuaFfA%253D%253D; password=31567518v43v43b3975711da84e068fa78; chat_token=P38SgjlpTok4KfdfvbedfvnRKIxWuAxK4OHBkWBLnlrDe%2BxMNQ%3D; user_id=78001175; real_user_id=78001175; social_id=296400; __auc=333d543ga154208ab39c1e7529ec; OAGEO=NL%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C; OAID=d4f0c5982d3sdfva46de6bf377999630; _ym_uid=1460834849654078056; __utma=4986037.946172708.1460834854.1460841308.1460868718.3; __utmc=4986037; __utmz=4986037.1460834854.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _ym_isad=2; __unam=7639673-154208d00a"

var arr = someString.split(';');
arr[0] = arr[0].replace(/.*?> (.*)$/,'$1');
var arLen = arr.length;
for(var i = 0; i < arLen; i++){
$('body').append(arr[i]+'</br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Куда весь этот код ? что он делает ?

Comment: Разбивает вашу строку, или как вы хотели?

Comment: Если же вам нужно вытащить всю строку     HTTP_COOKIE то прошу скинуть что перед ней и за ней, без этой информации не смогу помочь с регуляркой

Answer (score 0):

Ваша регулярка РАБОТАЕТ для указанного вами примера.

Запрос может возвращаться с переносом строки, а `.` не отвечает за `\n` - перенос строки.

Если я прав, то должно сработать следующее `/_COOKIE(.|\s)*?<\/td><\/tr>/m`

```js
function OnLoadMy(){
  str="ненужный текст HTTP_COOKIE => __cfduid"+"\n"+"=d7a5bc6e25f6043evev21781dbb1d591bd8b1460834789; cf_clearance=b743425f1830b8averea106810887d155501c350d-1460834814-604800; login=yXRWPuMMQ2sd dfSgc%252F0KM985nSZ6cDNwuaFfA%253D%253D; password=31567518v43v43b3975711da84e068fa78; chat_token=P38SgjlpTok4KfdfvbedfvnRKIxWuAxK4OHBkWBLnlrDe%2BxMNQ%3D; user_id=78001175; real_user_id=78001175; social_id=296400; __auc=333d543ga154208ab39c1e7529ec; OAGEO=NL%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C; OAID=d4f0c5982d3sdfva46de6bf377999630; _ym_uid=1460834849654078056; __utma=4986037.946172708.1460834854.1460841308.1460868718.3; __utmc=4986037; __utmz=4986037.1460834854.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _ym_isad=2; __unam=7639673-154208d00a</td></tr> ненужный текст";
  regex =/_COOKIE(.|\s)*?<\/td><\/tr>/m;
  result = str.match(regex);
  alert("result = " + result);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body onload="OnLoadMy()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А так найдет вообще все `regex =/[\s\S]*/;`
`\s` - все пробельные символы `\S` - все не пробельные символы